# Check url for specific text, download if it matches, continue to next if name cannot be resolved

Tags: powershell, error-handling

I need this script to do the following:

1. Verify certain strings or regex of `$url` to verify I'm not being redirected (e.g. [This address](https://zeustracker.abuse.ch/blocklist.php?download=badips) is valid, [this address](https://zeustracker.abuse.ch/blocklist.php?download=blahblah) is not and redirects to the homepage.) prior to downloading,
2. Continue to process sources.txt even if "The remote name could not be resolved:" occurs (I'm attempting to download blocklists, some of them get DDoS'd fairly regularly).

**Current Behavior:** Script is processing 3 of 5 `$url`s.  The 3rd errors out to a bogus address (on purpose), so do the 4th and 5th.  However, the 4th and 5th are never attempted.

```
try {
    import-Csv $intelSource | ForEach-Object {
         $storageDir = "$($intelDir)\$($_.threatType) $($_.threatSubtype)"
         $storageName = (Get-Culture).TextInfo
         $threat = $_.threatType + "_" + $_.threatSubtype    # Set this variable to save headaches passing it later
         $storageFile = "$($storageDir)\$($threat)_$($(get-date -f MM-dd-yy)).csv"    # Filename specified by sources.csv fields and today's date
         $url = $_.threatLocation
         if((Test-Path $storageDir) -eq 0) {
            mkdir $storageName.ToTitleCase($storageDir.ToLower());
            }
         # Begin Error Logging
         try {
            $intelCount++
            $webclient.DownloadFile($url,$storageFile)
         }
         catch {
            $intelErrorCount++
            $intelError = "" | Select "Time","Item","Message"
            $intelError.time = get-date -f G
            $intelError.item = $threat
            $intelError.message = $_.Exception.Message
            $errorLog += $intelError
            $intelError = $null
            echo $_.Exception|format-list -force | Out-File $intelDir\$threat"_ErrorLog_"$(get-date -f MM-dd-yy).txt -Append
            Write-Host $_.Exception
            Continue
         }
         # End Error Logging
         # Cleanup
         finally {
            $webclient.Dispose()
         }
         # Throttling (mainly future use with multiple sources)
         Start-Sleep 5
     }
}
finally { 
    if ($intelErrorCount -gt 0) {
        # Table Generation
        $errorLogTable = $errorLog | New-HTMLTable
        $HTML = New-HTMLHead
        $HTML += "<h3>Threat Intel Feed - Errors</h3>"
        $HTML += $errorLogTable | Close-HTML
        $email.Item('Subject') += "$($intelErrorCount) Error(s)"
        $email.Item('Body') += "$($intelErrorCount) of $($intelCount) sources failed. See attached for verbose log(s) `r`n`r`n $($HTML)"
        Get-ChildItem -Path $intelDir | Where {$_.Name -match "$($(get-date -f MM-dd-yy))"} | foreach{$_.fullname} | Send-MailMessage @email -bodyashtml
    }
    else {
        $email.Item('Subject') += "Success"
        $email.Item('Body') += "No errors for $($intelCount) sources."
        Send-MailMessage @email
    }
    $intelErrorCount = $null
    $intelCount = $null
    $errorLogTable = $null
    $errorLog = $null
}
```

Comment: I'm surprised it works more than once. Why do you `Dispose()` the `$WebClient` object after every attempt?

Comment: @mathias-r-jessen I'm relatively (read entirely) new to scripting something this involved, let alone in powershell.  Saw it used in a download file snippet so I incorporated it.  Moving it into the `finally{}` currently holding the reporting elements doesn't change how it's acting after an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the Continue statement. Continue and Break don't work in a foreach-object script block as you'd expect. Change to a foreach statement:

```
foreach ($_ in (import-Csv $intelSource) {
  # Your existing code will probably work as is here
  # But you might want to rename $_ since it is an automatic variable
}
```

Comment: I actually *just* figured this out as well.  I went the route of setting `$ErrorActionPreference = "Continue"` by way of deleting it at all (apparently `Continue` is the default EAP value).  Then I deleted the `Continue` Statement from my Catch block.  Do you know of any issues I may have caused by going this route instead of via your suggestion?

Comment: I'm guessing that means your catch block isn't getting executed any longer.  If so then the error recording logic there is getting skipped. The only other difference I can see is that start-sleep is always executed (vs skipped if you left the Continue in place).

Comment: The catch block is still getting executed, it's still generating the files and html items.

Comment: Ok, then the sleep would be the only difference that comes to mind. I'm curious as to what the difference is when you set EAP to Continue versus some other value.

Comment: Well, with `Continue` being the default, it does what you would think (so long as `Continue` isn't present in the Catch block as that references an `inner loop` which I don't have to switch over to.  Setting it to `Stop` would obviously stop processing on any terminating error (and non-terminating I believe), `Continue Silently` would be interesting since I have error handling via the `Catch` block but *should* prevent any errors from being logged into `$error`.